# Get a nullable var from a class

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, nullable

Let me start off by saying my Kotlin experience is limited. I am trying to get a nullable `var` from a class, but get a null pointer whenever I execute it.

Class code:

```
class MultiSpinner : Spinner, OnMultiChoiceClickListener, OnCancelListener {

    private var items: List<String>? = null
    private var selected: BooleanArray? = null
    private var selectedNew: BooleanArray? = null
    private var defaultText: String? = null
    private var listener: MultiSpinnerListener? = null
    var category: String = "010"

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(arg0: Context, arg1: AttributeSet) : super(arg0, arg1) {}

    constructor(arg0: Context, arg1: AttributeSet, arg2: Int) : super(arg0, arg1, arg2) {}

    override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int, isChecked: Boolean) {
        selectedNew!![which] = isChecked
    }

    override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        // refresh text on spinner
        val spinnerBuffer = StringBuffer()
        var allUnselected = true
        for (i in items!!.indices) {
            if (selected!![i]) {
                spinnerBuffer.append(items!![i])
                spinnerBuffer.append(", ")
                allUnselected = false
            }
            selectedNew!![i] = selected!![i]
        }

        var spinnerText: String?
        if (allUnselected) {
            spinnerText = defaultText
        } else {
            spinnerText = spinnerBuffer.toString()

            /** Remove trailing comma*/
            spinnerText = spinnerText.substring(0, spinnerText.length - 2)
        }
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            context,
            R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            arrayOf(spinnerText)
        )
        setAdapter(adapter)

        category = selected!!.joinToString(limit = selected!!.size, separator = "") {it.toInt().toString()}
        listener!!.onItemsSelected(selected)
    }

    override fun performClick(): Boolean {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(
            items!!.toTypedArray(), selectedNew, this
        )
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok
        ) { dialog, _ -> selected = selectedNew!!.copyOf(); dialog.cancel() }
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel
        ) { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
        builder.setOnCancelListener(this)
        builder.show()
        return true
    }

    fun setItems(
        items: List<String>, allText: String,
        listener: MultiSpinnerListener
    ) {
        this.items = items
        this.defaultText = allText
        this.listener = listener

        // one selected by default
        selected = BooleanArray(items.size) {false}
        selectedNew = BooleanArray(items.size) {false}
        for (i in selected!!.indices) {
            selected!![i] = false
            selectedNew!![i] = false
        }

        selected!![0] = true
        selectedNew!![0] = true
        category = selected!!.joinToString(limit = selected!!.size, separator = "") {it.toInt().toString()}

        // all text on the spinner
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            context,
            R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayOf(allText)
        )
        setAdapter(adapter)
    }

    fun getSelected(): BooleanArray? {
        return selected
    }

    interface MultiSpinnerListener {
        fun onItemsSelected(selected: BooleanArray?)
    }

    private fun Boolean.toInt() = if (this) 1 else 0
}
```

Initializing

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    val spinnerCategory: MultiSpinner = findViewById(R.id.category_spinner)
    val categoryList: List<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.category).toList()

    spinnerCategory.setItems(categoryList, getString(R.string.default_category), this)
    ...
}
```

Accessing `selected` from `MultiSpinner`

```
val selected: BooleanArray? = MultiSpinner(this).getSelected()
println(selected)
```

The println reads `null`.

I have tried returning `BooleanArray` in stead of `BooleanArray?` for `getSelected`, but that just gave me a null pointer exception (as expected from the println reading).

I circumvented the problem for now by using `category` in the class and performing the manipulation inside the class. However, I would like to get the `selected` array in my main activity, and use its data to create my desired String outside of the class.

Why do I not get my `selected` data but instead a null pointer?

Comment: Where is your `getSelected()` call placed? Is it in `onCreate` too?

Comment: Only see your comment now, it is used outside `onCreate` in another function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access `selected` using the instance obtained from `findViewById` (the one already existing in your view hierarchy) instead of creating a completely new object by yourself:

```
val selected: BooleanArray? = spinnerCategory.getSelected()
```

---

Edit:

If you need to access `selected` outside the `onCreate` method simply store `spinnerCategory` as a property instead of a local variable:

```
private lateinit var spinnerCategory: MultiSpinner

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    spinnerCategory = findViewById(R.id.category_spinner)
    ...
}
```

Also Kotlin has a nice feature for Android called [View Binding](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding) which allows you to omit calling `findViewById` and reference your views using their ids directly:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    category_spinner.setItems(categoryList, getString(R.string.default_category), this)
    ...
}

private fun doSomethingWithSelected() {
    val selected: BooleanArray? = category_spinner.getSelected()
}
```

However in that case **I'd recommend changing the view's id so it agrees with the Kotlin variable naming guidelines**, e.g. to `spinnerCategory` as it's already being used.

Comment: How would I access `spinnerCategory` when it gets destroyed at the end of the scope in `onCreate()`?

Comment: @NSimons I've added some additional information to my answer.

Comment: thanks, I used your first suggestion for now, will look into view binding when I have some more time

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `selected` with `null` meaning it can be nullable, so the compiler think it might possible that you will get null in this parameter.
If you don't want it to be null you can define the variable like so:

```
private var selected: BooleanArray = false
```

Now `selected` parameter won't be nullable at any time.

Comment: The problem is not whether it can contain `null`, but rather why I am getting `null`

Comment: In that case, you need to access `spinnerCategory` because the object is created inside the `onCreate` method. If you want to access it from outside of the method you should do: `var spinnerCategory: MultiSpinner
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        spinnerCategory: = findViewById(R.id.category_spinner)
        val categoryList: List<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.category).toList()

        spinnerCategory.setItems(categoryList, getString(R.string.default_category), this)
        ...
    }`

Comment: thanks, this worked (with some additions). using `private lateinit var spinnerCategory: MultiSpinner` did the trick.